# Python RE with parentheses in input?

Tags: python, regex

using re.match and re.groupdict() to parse long lines with parentheses in input.  These are raw `r'strings'`, but the parentheses in the input result in a no match.  When i take out the parentheses from the fake input, the re works.  Since these are raw strings, what is the best way to handle this, removing the parentheses from the input is not really a good option.

Comment: post an ex along with expected output.

Comment: Parentheses are regexp operators, you have to escape them if you want to match them literally.

Comment: Read a good regexp tutorial, it will tell you which characters are special.